# Cannot make regex working on HTML pattern attribute

Tags: html, regex, pattern-matching

My **regex** works fine on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and my regex is

```
[1-4]|(0)
```

But when I tried it on HTML input element's attribute it doesn't work as expected. My HTML is like below

```
<form action="/">
     <input type="text" id="usernum" name="usernum" pattern="[1-4]|(0)" title="1-4 and must include at leat one 0">
     <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I want users must enter one **0** along with the ranges digit.

Comment: `|` is for alternatives. So that matches either 1 through 4 or 0. It's the same as `[0-4]`.

Comment: If i use ```[0-4]``` user can skip **0** but I want to force them to enter at least one **0**

Comment: I know. I'm just explaining what your code does. Why did you think `|0` would force a `0`?

Comment: Perhaps `^(?=.*0)[0-4]+$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pattern` attribute has to match the entire input.

```
([1-4]+0[0-4]*|[0-4]*0[1-4]+)+
```

The first alternative requires at least one digit `1-4` before a `0`, the second requires at least one digit `1-4` after a `0`. Then repeat it with `+` to allow more than one `0`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lw4f5y/1)